# Ansible docker_volume module is not present

Tags: docker, ansible, alpine

Even acomplish with requirements https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/docker_volume_module.html

> python >= 2.6 (2.7.13)
>   docker-py >= 1.10.0 (1.10.6)

I cannot use docker_volume in playbooks. Other docker modules are already installed:

```
bash-4.3# ansible-doc -l | grep docker 

docker manage docker containers 
docker_container manage docker containers 
docker_image Manage docker images. 
docker_image_facts Inspect docker images 
docker_login Log into a Docker registry. 
docker_network Manage Docker networks 
docker_service Manage docker services and containers.
```

I know that I can use shell command, but I want to know if there is a way to install docker_volume.

OS is alpine 3.6 in a docker image created for this pourpose.

Info about docker-py:

```
bash-4.3# sudo pip show docker-py 

Name: docker-py 
Version: 1.10.6 
Summary: Python client for Docker. 
Home-page: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/ 
Author: Joffrey F 
Author-email: joffrey@docker.com 
License: UNKNOWN 
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
Requires: requests, backports.ssl-match-hostname, ipaddress, docker-pycreds, websocket-client, six
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker_volume` is introduced in Ansible 2.4, as stated in the documentation:

> New in version 2.4.

You should upgrade Ansible to latest version to get this module.